# `event` throws TypeError caused by WeakKeyDictionary when tuple is passed

Tags: python-hypothesis

I wanted to see the statistics of list values and I passed the value to `event()` after converting it to tuple to make it hashable.

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Foo:
    x: int
    y: str

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))

@given(lists(builds(Foo, integers(), text()), max_size=3))
def test_foo(l):
    t = tuple(l)
    event(t)
```

However, it still doesn't work because of the following error:

```
self = <WeakKeyDictionary at 0x105c17430>, key = ()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
>       return self.data[ref(key)]
E       TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'tuple' object

../../../.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/weakref.py:416: TypeError
```

Because tuple is builtin, I don't come up with the easy work around. I'm interested in how others are doing when they want to see list/tuple values with `event()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I'll take this as a bug report - as a workaround you can convert to `str`, since events are always counted as strings in the end anyway.

(update: fixed a few hours later)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'll post this to the upstream issue tracker as well.